# What is the correct order to read the Neverwar series?

Tags: suggested-order, colin-rutherford, neverwar

What is the correct order to read the Colin Rutherford series "*Neverwar*"?

**I want to read it based on when the books came out.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my brief research there are only three books (presently) in the 'Tales of the Neverwar' series although future books are planned;

- "[Souls of the Never](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23348814-souls-of-the-never)" - Published in Sept 2014
- "[Origins of the Never: A prequel to Souls of the Never](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23514470-origins-of-the-never)" - A brief novella Published in Oct 2014
- "[Worlds of the Never](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Worlds-Never-Tales-Neverwar-Book-ebook/dp/B00TH5BC1U/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8)" - Published in April 2015.

All the reviews I've read suggest that you should read them in published order, even though the second one is technically a prequel.

Comment: ok thanks. it was the prequel that was messing me up. i could never figure out which one it was, and when to read it.

Comment: @albusseveruspotter - Always glad to be of assistance. I puzzled over it for a while.